# convert NamedPipeConnection delegate from C# to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, delegates

How I can convert the following code in C# to VB.Net

```
   client.ServerMessage += delegate (NamedPipeConnection<SomeClass, SomeClass> conn, SomeClass message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server says: {0}", message.Response);
        };
```

I tried many things but I couldn't do it correctly.

Comment: You can't directly, because that code uses an anonymous method, which was never supported in VB. You will need to either use a delegate to a named method or else use a lambda expression, which are basically an evolution of anonymous methods and are supported in VB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, that C# code uses an anonymous method, which is a feature not supported by VB. You could use a named method in C# like this:

```cs
private void DisplayMessage(NamedPipeConnection<SomeClass, SomeClass> conn, SomeClass message)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Server says: {0}", message.Response);
}
```

and then:

```cs
client.ServerMessage += DisplayMessage;
```

The equivalent of that in VB would be this:

```vb
Private Sub DisplayMessage(conn As NamedPipeConnection(Of SomeClass, SomeClass), message As SomeClass)
    Console.WriteLine("Server says: {0}", message.Response)
End Sub
```

I don't know what `client.ServerMessage` is but, while this is not completely equivalent to the C# code, the following would probably work if it's a property:

```vb
client.ServerMessage = AddressOf DisplayMessage
```

If it's an event, you can do this:

```vb
AddHandler client.ServerMessage, AddressOf DisplayMessage
```

With the introduction of LINQ, we now have Lambda Expressions, which are an evolution of anonymous methods that are supported in both C# and VB. The C# code would be like this:

```cs
client.ServerMessage += (NamedPipeConnection<SomeClass, SomeClass> conn, SomeClass message) => Console.WriteLine("Server says: {0}", message.Response);
```

or, if the parameter types can be inferred, just this:

```cs
client.ServerMessage += (conn, message) => Console.WriteLine("Server says: {0}", message.Response);
```

Once again, the corresponding VB depends on what `client.ServerMessage` is and close enough may be close enough:

```vb
client.ServerMessage = Sub(conn As NamedPipeConnection(Of SomeClass, SomeClass), message As SomeClass) Console.WriteLine("Server says: {0}", message.Response)
```

or:

```vb
AddHandler client.ServerMessage, Sub(conn As NamedPipeConnection(Of SomeClass, SomeClass), message As SomeClass) Console.WriteLine("Server says: {0}", message.Response)
```

Again, you can omit the parameter types if they can be inferred:

```vb
client.ServerMessage = Sub(conn, message) Console.WriteLine("Server says: {0}", message.Response)
```

or:

```vb
AddHandler client.ServerMessage, Sub(conn, message) Console.WriteLine("Server says: {0}", message.Response)
```